# GPIO pins in Python Script work in IDLE3 but not when run from console (using Adafruit IO MQTT)

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, gpio, adafruit

UPDATE: Problem solved.  Sigh.  It was as simple as adding a bit of a delay when turning the pins on and off.  Not a permissions issue at all.  I guess the IDLE3 ide ran just the littlest bit slower that the signal was detected by the arduino.  When running it from the console, it happened too quickly.  Adding a time.sleep(.5) between switching the pins from Low to High gave the ard enough time to read.  Everything works now.

I've got a python script that functions as a MQTT client as well as controls some GPIO pins based on signals it gets from the MQTT feeds.  This script works without issue when run from IDLE3.  However, when I try to run it at startup using both /etc/rc.local and crontab (I've used both, separately, to no avail) or from the console, the script runs (and I know because I see it publishing to a MQTT feed) but the GPIO pins do not function.

The script is:

```
import sys
import RPI.GPIO as GPIO
import serial
import time

from Adafruit_IO import MQTTClient

ADAFRUIT_IO_KEY = 'mykeyhere'
ADAFRUIT_IO_USERNAME = 'myusernamehere'

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

FEED_ID = 'DoorFeed'
reset_feed_id = 'GameReset'

door_override = 18
reset_pin = 17

GPIO.setup(door_override, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(reset_pin, GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.output(door_override, True)
GPIO.output(reset_pin, True)

def connected(client):
    print('connected to adafruit io')
    client.subscribe(FEED_ID)
    client.subscribe(reset_feed_id)

def disconnected(client):
    print('disconnected from adafruit io')
    client.connect()

def handle_msg(payload):
    if(payload == '1'):
        GPIO.output(door_override, False)
        print('manual override sent')
        GPIO.output(door_override, True)

def handle_reset(payload):
    if(payload == '1'):
        GPIO.output(reset_pin, False)
        print('reset signal sent')
        GPIO.output(reset_pin, True)
        client.publish('GameReset', 'F')

def message(client, feed_id, payload):
    print('feed {0} received new value {1}'.format(feed_id, payload))
    if(feed_id == 'GameReset'):
        handle_reset(payload)
    if(feed_id == 'DoorFeed'):
        handle_msg(payload)

client = MQTTClient(ADAFRUIT_IO_USERNAME, ADAFRUIT_IO_KEY)

client.on_connect = connected
client.on_disconnect = disconnected
client.on_message = message

client.connect()

client.loop_blocking()
```

When this is run from IDLE, the output pins work.  They're connected to an arduino and used to manually control a switch or to break the arduino out of a loop it's in.  However, when I run the script from the console or from startup, the MQTT client aspects of the code work, but not the GPIO pins.

The two methods I've tried for running this at start up are

sudo nano /etc/rc.local

i add the line of code:
sudo python3 /home/pi/dogflapcontrol2.py &

I've also tried doing the @reboot in crontab.  Both methods allow the program to run as the MQTT responds, but not the pins.  I added a 30 and 60 second time delay in the script to see if that would help, but it hasn't made a difference.  The best I can figure is that there's some sort of permission issue?  But when running it, i'm using sudo, so I would have thought that would solve that issue.

Any thoughts or feedback anyone has would be tremendously helpful!  Many thanks. Oh! I'm using a RPi0W

Comment: Do you run IDLE3 using `sudo`?

Comment: I also tried the same program on my RPi 3 and got the same result, no GPIO pins

Comment: (I should add I'm still new to RPi and Linux)  I've just been opening IDLE3 from the start menu>programming tab.  so quite possibly no?

Comment: It could be that some variables are set (like `PYTHONPATH`) when you run IDLE3 but are not set when you use `sudo`, however I would expect error messages if that was the case.

Comment: Are there any settings I should look at or try changing? Would errors boot the program or is there another way to monitor for errors that’s not immediately apparent?

Comment: Didn't you try it from a command-line (shell)?   That would be the place to test and you would see errors at once.  I don't have your system type so can't advise on settings.